# How to Omit multiple properties in a succint way using Omit<>

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the following type definition I am using `Omit` two time to remove two property from `B` definition.
I would like to know if it is possible to use only a single `Omit` but removing two or more properties in one shot.

```
export type A = Readonly<{
  x: number;
  y: number;
  j: string;
  k: string;
}>;

export type B = Omit<A, 'j'> & Omit<A, 'k'>
```

Comment: Pretty sure that `&` will not have the effect you want. It will be a type that at the same time is `A without j` and `A without b` which does not really mean `A without and b`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCcC8cBKwCGAJhAHYA2iAPAN4BQccIAXHCQK4C2ARsFANz04iFu268BDAFYsAzjCgBLEgHMJcANaz5S1bQC+APgG1QkWAmSoAQljgB5DgpiU0AGjgBySR4NwAZPaOzm6e6j60ZMDwEEw22HQMzHAAjK6CwinugtJwAES5aQyaebn6QA

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You just need to use a union as the second type parameter to remove all constituents in the union from the first type parameter:

```
export type A = Readonly<{
  x: number;
  y: number;
  j: string;
  k: string;
}>;

export type B = Omit<A, 'j' | 'k'>
// Same as
// type B = {
//     readonly x: number;
//     readonly y: number;
// }
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCcC8cBKwCGAJhAHYA2iAPAN4BQccIAXHCQK4C2ARsFANz04iFu268BDAFYsAzjCgBLEgHMJcANaz5S1bQC+APgG1QkWAmSoAQljgB5DgpiU0AGjgBySR7gAfT+oeBrQA9CFwAMr4HKj4MqHhSChwNth0YQyZUATE5IiMIpw8-AmZDNlEpBRChWIlGXpAA)